# How do I model this experiment for a real world analysis?

Tags: experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics, experimental-technique, models

I did an experiment of finding the band gap of semiconductors. In this I determined the energy gap of the material of the given thermistor. I was wondering how many parameters must be considered that obstruct and distort my result(because I ain't performing this experiment in a perfect laboratory conditions under vacuum).
This is a picture of the setup:
[image]
Of course I am taking as many readings as possible and repeating the experiment multiple times to obtain the best statistical approximation, but what would affect my setup given the following conditions of the room I performed my experiment in:
1. Room temperature- 28degree Celsius

2. Number of fans- 6 fans that were switched on which would cause forced cooling on my apparatus which heats the coil of resistance,R.
3. Closed room, not prone to outside environmental effects.
4. The heater that was heating the coil had a cardboard on top covering the lid(which had 3 holes of the size of 1cm each; one for the coil, second for the thermometer and the third left open).
5. The temperature recorded by the thermometer was recorded using a digital display device connected to the thermometer.
6. Least count of the ammeter and voltmeter(multimeter) is 1units.
7. The heater used is cylindrically shaped, white in colour, and the coil placed inside was made of copper and was helically shaped.
8. Average reflex time for taking down readings=0.25 seconds

Given all these conditions, is it possible to obtain a master equation that includes all the external effects included in the main equation of finding the band gap, I.e., resistance,
R=Aexp(B/T) 
Where A is the initial resistance, and B is related to the energy gap as 
B=E/2k, where k is the Boltzmann constant.
I am doing this to understand the essence of performing an experiment and analysing how important the small things are, which could potentially distort the result. I would also appreciate feedback on how best to statistically analyse this experiment.